# how to add website intro or take tour

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

i want to create website intro or "Take tour" like if your press a button it will take you different pages and show you the functionality just like in stack overflow and other website,i want some example or tutorials related to it

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: i wanted tutorial i think you can understand that much or are you just trying to act cool

Comment: No, I did not understand that, since your ‘question’ is *so* [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, asking for tutorials is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [bootstrap tour](http://bootstraptour.com/).

Comment: thanks man nice example